# How to describe changing some words to match what has been used elsewhere

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

Assume I am building an application which contains various error messages. Some of them say:

- error on phase X
- error on phase Y
- ...

and others say:

- problem on phase A
- problem on phase B
- ...

At some point I decide to change all instances of the word `problem` in the error messages to the word `error`. Thus the error messages now look the same:

- error on phase X
- error on phase Y
- error on phase A
- error on phase B
- ...

I want to describe this change I did. How would I say it? What I've come up so far, which I do not think is good, is the following:

- Aligned error messages.
- Unified error messages.
- Synchronized error messages.

Comment: The question being closed is absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many words can be used to fill the blank space in this sentence

I _____ the error messages

In the sense of "fixed"

- fixed
- tailored
- doctored
- hammered
- whipped

In the sense of "matched"

- matched
- equated
- squared
- regularised
- standardised
- aligned (you have said it)
- normalised
- homogeniged
- made consistent
- paragoned (to equal or surpass, to compare)
- made identical

In the sense of "redid"

- redid
- recalibrated
- reworded
- retitled
- rendered
- repatterned

In the sense of "duplicated"

- duplicated
- dittoed
- facsimiled
- mimeoed (to print copies from (a prepared stencil) using a mimeograph)

In the sense of "removing unwanted things"

- culled
- scrubbed

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **standardise**.

> *standardization* noun [U] (UK usually standardisation)
>
> the process of making things of the same type all have the same
> basic features: ...
>
> - *Part of the standardization process involved changing the names of all the hospitals.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/standardization)]

However, I'd avoid the string  'standardised error messages' as it's misleading. I'd use something like "... standardised the naming of hitherto variously named error messages, now using solely the term 'error messages'."